# How to add month list as SQL condition?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, while-loop, request

In a report page I have :

- Month : Select the needed month
- Work Day : the number of work day on my month
- Year : The needed year

Now I have to change it with :

- Start Month : Select the first month of my period
- End month : Selectthe final month of my period
- Work Day : the number of work day on my month
- Year : The needed year

Everything is okay in my Report, I want to change my SQL request to have something like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 
 While (not my final month)
     {mytable.month = current month}
 AND mytable.day = @workDay
 AND mytable.year = @year
```

And I dont know how to manage the `while` in a `WHERE` And I don't find how.

Data exemple :

```
| ID | Label | Month | Year | Nd_Days | 
---------------------------------------
| 01 |  foo  |  02   | 2016 |    2    | 
| 02 |  fii  |  03   | 2016 |    1    | 
| 03 |  faa  |  04   | 2016 |    1    | 
| 04 |  fii  |  03   | 2016 |    3    |
```

Comment: in mysql while-loop not work with select query you can use it with stored procedurs

Comment: Check the manual for `WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`

Comment: whats wrong with expanding the tables and adding a join?

Comment: Show us an example set of inputs

Comment: Thanks to you, the between doesn't do the work, but it help me find how to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how to do that. And in a easy way, I feel stupid to not find it alone.
The comment helped me.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 
 mytable.month >= @firstmonth
 AND mytable.month <= @finalmonth
 AND mytable.day = @workDay
 AND mytable.year = @year
```